# JavaFX Line Chart does not update well. Data problems

Tags: javafx, charts

I got werid bug with updating data on LineChart. After updating LineChart `x` values does not update well. Looks like new values from function are "mixed". After implementation of [Wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet)

With dispersive and without it, should looks like on current animation from wikipedia right side of the page for both of cases. Trying to catch this problem what is wrong, but honestly i can not see that. Counting data pretty sure is in 100% good. I red about this kind of problems somewhere but could not resolve my problem.

Main class :

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Animation 1D");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1200, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Axes class :

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;

public class Axes {
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private double xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, xTickUnit, yTickUnit;
    private int axesWidth, axesHeight;

    public Axes() {
        this.xMin = 0;
        this.xMax = 0;
        this.yMin = 0;
        this.yMax = 0;
        this.xTickUnit = 0;
        this.yTickUnit = 0;
        this.axesWidth = 0;
        this.axesHeight = 0;
    }

    public NumberAxis getXAxis() {
        return xAxis;
    }

    public NumberAxis getYAxis() {
        return yAxis;
    }

    public int getAxesWidth() {
        return axesWidth;
    }

    public void setAxesWidth(int axesWidth) {
        this.axesWidth = axesWidth;
    }

    public int getAxesHeight() {
        return axesHeight;
    }

    public void setAxesHeight(int axesHeight) {
        this.axesHeight = axesHeight;
    }

    public double getxMin() {
        return xMin;
    }

    public void setxMin(double xMin) {
        this.xMin = xMin;
    }

    public double getxMax() {
        return xMax;
    }

    public void setxMax(double xMax) {
        this.xMax = xMax;
    }

    public double getyMin() {
        return yMin;
    }

    public void setyMin(double yMin) {
        this.yMin = yMin;
    }

    public double getyMax() {
        return yMax;
    }

    public void setyMax(double yMax) {
        this.yMax = yMax;
    }

    public double getxTickUnit() {
        return xTickUnit;
    }

    public void setxTickUnit(double xTickUnit) {
        this.xTickUnit = xTickUnit;
    }

    public double getyTickUnit() {
        return yTickUnit;
    }

    public void setyTickUnit(double yTickUnit) {
        this.yTickUnit = yTickUnit;
    }

}
```

Controller class :

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.packet3D.Window3DController;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, xTick, yTick, width, height;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis xAxis, yAxis;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
    @FXML
    private LineChart<Double, Double> axesTest;
    @FXML
    private Label timeLabel;

    private GaussianWave gaussianWave;
    private GaussianWaveDispersive gaussianWaveDispersive;


    private Axes axes;

    private Series<Double, Double> series;

    private Timeline timeLine;
    @FXML
    public void initialize() 
    {
        System.out.println("Initialising...");
        axes = new Axes();

        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        xMin.setText("-30");
        xMax.setText("30");

        axesTest.setCreateSymbols(false);

        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Gaussian Wave : non-Dispersive", "Gaussian Wave : Dispersive");
        //comboBox.getItems().addAll("Gaussian Wave : non-Dispersive");
        series = new XYChart.Series<Double, Double>();

        timeLine = new Timeline();

        applyButtonClicked(null);
    }

    public void applyButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        System.out.println("Applying new parameters...");

        axes.setxMin(Double.parseDouble(xMin.getText()));
        axes.setxMax(Double.parseDouble(xMax.getText()));
        axes.setyMin(Double.parseDouble(yMin.getText()));
        axes.setyMax(Double.parseDouble(yMax.getText()));
        axes.setxTickUnit(Double.parseDouble(xTick.getText()));
        axes.setyTickUnit(Double.parseDouble(yTick.getText()));
        axes.setAxesWidth(Integer.parseInt(width.getText()));
        axes.setAxesHeight(Integer.parseInt(height.getText()));

        xAxis.setSide(Side.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        xAxis.setPrefWidth(axes.getAxesWidth());
        xAxis.setLayoutY(axes.getAxesHeight()/2);
        xAxis.autosize();

        xAxis.setLowerBound(axes.getxMin());
        xAxis.setUpperBound(axes.getxMax());
        xAxis.setTickUnit(axes.getxTickUnit());

        yAxis.setSide(Side.LEFT);
        yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        yAxis.setPrefHeight(axes.getAxesHeight());

        yAxis.setLowerBound(axes.getyMin());
        yAxis.setUpperBound(axes.getyMax());
        yAxis.setTickUnit(axes.getyTickUnit());


    }
    @FXML
    public void startButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        if (comboBox.getValue() == null) 
        {
            System.out.print("Nie wybrano opcji.");
        }
        else
        {
            if(comboBox.getValue().equals("Gaussian Wave : non-Dispersive")) 
            {
                System.out.println("Gaussian Wave : non-Dispersive");
                axesTest.setTitle("Gaussian Wave : non-Dispersive");

                if (series != null)
                {
                    series = new XYChart.Series<Double, Double>();
                }
                timeLine = new Timeline();
                gaussianWave = new GaussianWave( series, axes, timeLine );
                series = gaussianWave.draw();
                System.out.println("Rozmiar series: "+series.getData().size());
                gaussianWave.update(axesTest);


                axesTest.getData().add(series);
            }
            else if(comboBox.getValue().equals("Gaussian Wave : Dispersive")) 
            {
                System.out.println("Gaussian Wave : Dispersive");
                axesTest.setTitle("Gaussian Wave : Dispersive");

                if (series != null)
                {
                    series = new XYChart.Series<Double, Double>();
                }
                timeLine = new Timeline();
                gaussianWaveDispersive = new GaussianWaveDispersive( series, axes, timeLine );
                series = gaussianWaveDispersive.draw();
                System.out.println("Rozmiar series: "+series.getData().size());
                gaussianWaveDispersive.update(axesTest);

                axesTest.getData().add(series); 
    //            axesTest.setTitle("Gaussian Wave : Dispersive");
    //            gaussianWaveDispersive = new GaussianWaveDispersive(series, axes);
    //            series = gaussianWaveDispersive.draw();
    //
    //            gaussianWaveDispersive.update(axesTest);
    //
    //            axesTest.getData().add(series);
            }
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void restartButtonClicked() {
        System.out.println("Restarting...");
        timeLine.getKeyFrames().clear();
        axesTest.getData().clear();
    }

    @FXML
    public void stopButtonClicked() {
        System.out.println("Stopping...");

        System.out.println("Restarting...");
        timeLine.getKeyFrames().clear();
        axesTest.getData().clear();  
        timeLine.stop();
    }

    @FXML
    public void moveTo3DScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage stage3D = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("packet3D/Window3DSceneView.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Window3DController controller = loader.getController();
        stage3D.setTitle("Animation 3D");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800, false, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> controller.onKeyPressed(e));
        stage3D.setScene(scene);
        stage3D.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void comboBoxAction() {

    }


}
```

Interface class :

```
package sample;


import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

public interface Countable {
    public abstract void methodCounting();
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public abstract XYChart.Series draw();
    public abstract void update(LineChart<Double, Double> lineChart);
}
```

FXML class generated via Scene Builder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1025.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <left>
        <VBox prefHeight="574.0" prefWidth="270.0" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <GridPane hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <TextField promptText="xMin" text="-1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" fx:id="xMin" />
                        <TextField promptText="xMax" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="3" fx:id="xMax" />
                        <TextField fx:id="yMin" promptText="yMin" text="-1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <TextField fx:id="yMax" promptText="yMax" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <TextField fx:id="width" promptText="width" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <TextField fx:id="height" promptText="height" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <TextField promptText="xTick" text="0.1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" fx:id="xTick" />
                        <TextField fx:id="yTick" promptText="yTick" text="0.1" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="xMin" />
                  <Label text="yMin" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="xTick" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Width" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="Height" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="yTick" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="yMax" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="xMax" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
                    </children>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                    </padding>
                </GridPane>
                    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#applyButtonClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Zatwierdź">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
                <VBox>
                    <children>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" onAction="#comboBoxAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="25.0" right="25.0" top="10.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <HBox spacing="10.0">
                            <children>
                                <Button fx:id="startButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#startButtonClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Rozpotrznij">
                                    <HBox.margin>
                                        <Insets />
                                    </HBox.margin>
                                </Button>
                                <Button fx:id="restartButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#restartButtonClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Zatrzymaj" />
                            </children>
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                            <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                            </padding>
                        </HBox>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#stopButtonClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Stop">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" />
                           </HBox.margin></Button>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#moveTo3DScene" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Fala w przestrzeni 3D">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="25.0" right="25.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin></Button>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </children>
            <BorderPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
            </BorderPane.margin>
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
            </padding>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <LineChart fx:id="axesTest" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" stylesheets="@style.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <xAxis>
                <NumberAxis lowerBound="-10.0" side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxis" />
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" lowerBound="-10.0" side="LEFT" />
            </yAxis>
        </LineChart>
    </center>
   <top>
      <ToolBar prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="1025.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" text="JavaFX Simulation" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </Label>
            <Region prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="738.0" />
            <Label fx:id="timeLabel" text="Time : " />
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

2 logic classes counting waves :

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.function.Function;


public class GaussianWave implements Countable{



    private Function<Double, Double> gaussFunction;
    private XYChart.Series<Double, Double> series;
    private Axes axes;
    private Timeline timeline;

    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double xInc;
    private double time;

    public GaussianWave(XYChart.Series<Double, Double> series, Axes axes, Timeline timeLine) {
        this.axes = axes;
        //this.series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        this.series = series;
        this.timeline = timeLine;
        x = axes.getxMin();
        xInc = axes.getxTickUnit();
    }


    @Override
    public void methodCounting() {
        double lambda = 1;
            this.gaussFunction = x -> Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.exp(-(Math.pow((x - this.time), 2)))
                    * (Math.cos((2 * Math.PI * (x - this.time)) / lambda)), 2)
                    + Math.pow(Math.exp(-(Math.pow((x - this.time), 2)))
                    * (Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * (x - this.time)) / lambda)), 2));
    }

    @Override
    public Series<Double, Double> draw() {
        methodCounting();
        while(x < axes.getxMax()) {
            y = gaussFunction.apply(x);
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>( x , y));
            x += xInc;
        }
        return series;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(LineChart<Double, Double> lineChart) {
        System.out.println("Updating");
        this.timeline.getKeyFrames().add(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), e ->  {
                    for (XYChart.Series<Double, Double> series1 : lineChart.getData()) {
                        for (XYChart.Data<Double, Double> data : series1.getData()) {
                            Number y = gaussFunction.apply((double)data.getXValue());
                            data.setYValue((Double) y);
                            increaseTime();
                        }
                    }
                })
        );
        timeline.setCycleCount(1000);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        timeline.play();
    }


    public Function<Double, Double> getGaussFunction() {
        return gaussFunction;
    }

    public void setGaussFunction(Function<Double, Double> gaussFunction) {
        this.gaussFunction = gaussFunction;
    }

    public double getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(double time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void increaseTime(){
        this.time += 0.001;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

package sample;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.function.Function;


public class GaussianWaveDispersive implements Countable{



    private Function<Double, Double> gaussFunction;
    private Series<Double, Double> series;
    private Axes axes;
    private Timeline timeline;

    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double xInc;
    private double time;


    public GaussianWaveDispersive(XYChart.Series<Double, Double> series, Axes axes, Timeline timeLine) {
        this.axes = axes;
        //this.series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        this.series = series;
        this.timeline = timeLine;
        x = axes.getxMin();
        xInc = axes.getxTickUnit();
    }


    @Override
    public void methodCounting() {
        double lambda = 1;
        double k = (2 * Math.PI) / lambda;
            this.gaussFunction = x -> x =  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(1 / (Math.pow( ( 1 + Math.pow(4 * time, 2 )), (1/4)))
                    * Math.exp(-(( 1 / Math.pow(1 + (4 * time), 2)) * Math.pow(x - (k * time), 2) ))
                    * Math.cos((1/2) * Math.atan(-(2 * time)) + 1 / Math.pow(1 + (4 * time), 2)
                    * ((k + (2 * time * x)) * x - Math.pow(1/2 * time * k, 2))), 2)
                    + Math.pow(1 / (Math.pow( ( 1 + Math.pow(4 * time, 2 )), (1/4)))
                    * Math.exp(-(( 1 / Math.pow(1 + (4 * time), 2)) * Math.pow(x - (k * time), 2) ))
                    * Math.sin((1/2) * Math.atan(-(2 * time)) + 1 / Math.pow(1 + (4 * time), 2)
                    * ((k + (2 * time * x)) * x - Math.pow(1/2 * time * k, 2))), 2));
    }

    @Override
    public XYChart.Series<Double, Double> draw() {
        methodCounting();
        double count = 0;
        while(x < axes.getxMax()) {
            y = gaussFunction.apply(x);
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>( x , y));
            x += xInc;
            count ++;
            System.out.println("Ilosc : " + count + "x : " +x);
        }
        return series;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(LineChart<Double, Double> lineChart) {
        System.out.println("Updating");
        this.timeline.getKeyFrames().add(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), e ->  {
                    for (XYChart.Series<Double, Double> series1 : lineChart.getData()) {
                        for (XYChart.Data<Double, Double> data : series1.getData()) {
                            Number y = gaussFunction.apply((double)data.getXValue());
                            data.setYValue((Double) y);
                            increaseTime();
                        }
                    }
                })
        );
        timeline.setCycleCount(1000);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        timeline.play();
    }


    public Function<Double, Double> getGaussFunction() {
        return gaussFunction;
    }

    public void setGaussFunction(Function<Double, Double> gaussFunction) {
        this.gaussFunction = gaussFunction;
    }

    public double getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(double time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void increaseTime(){
        this.time += 0.001;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

For extrimly high for this kind of equantion `x` values we can observe there is hugh mess with data, should going smoothly like on wikipedia sample but it does not. Can someone tell me where is problem ? Also it's realy laggy while using small `x / y` tick and bigger `x` and `y` axes. What cause of that ? 
Thanks in advance.

P.S.
[image]

SS shows how it looks atm after few updating of linechart.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this problem close line go to settings scroll down to the apps select line deactivate mobile data open line something will come up saying Mobile Data is turned off select ok then close line go back to settings scroll down to the apps select line then turn on mobile data back on then close settings open line and its done

Comment: Not sure if this is even an answer to this question